# ¿Cual es la forma correcta de manejar arrays con useState React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Estoy creado una aplicacion (una tienda) en react y el problema surge cuando quiero crear una lista de componentes,
estos componentes tiene un boton para agregarlos en un carrito de compras.
Les comparto el codigo.

```
function ListCardProduct() {
  const { productdata } = useContext(ProductContext);
  const { cartData, setCartData } = useContext(ShoppingCartContext);

  const getDataProduct = (e) => {
    let getProduct = productdata.find((element) => element.id == e.target.id);
    let newProduct = {};
    if (cartData.length === 0) {
      newProduct = {
        ...getProduct,
        qty: 1,
      };
      setCartData([...cartData, newProduct]);
    }
```

La idea es que si no hay nada en el carrito añadirlo, de lo contrario verificar si ya existe el producto y aumentar la cantidad

```
`else {
      cartData.forEach((product) => {
        if (product.id == getProduct.id) {
          newProduct = {
            ...getProduct,
            qty: getProduct.qty ++,
          };
          let data = cartData.filter((e) => e.id != newProduct.id);
          setCartData([...data, newProduct]);
        } else {
          newProduct = {
            ...getProduct,
            qty: 1,
          };
          setCartData([...cartData, newProduct]);
        }
      });
    }
  };
```

Los pongo en contexto , presiono el boton de añadir del -elementoA- 2 veces , presiono el boton del -elementoB- 2 veces todo bien , al momento de volver a pressionar el boton del -elementoA- lo añade fuera es decir tengo 2 elementosA 2 elementosB y 1 elementoA,, si vulevo a presionar el -elementoA- se resetea por asi decirlo y vuelvo a tener 4 elementosA y 2 elementosB.Tiene que ver con algo de renderisado?

```
return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {productdata.map((product) => {
        return (
          <CardProduct
            key={product.id}
            productdata={product}
            getDataProduct={getDataProduct}
          />
        );
      })}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

resto de codigo

Answer (score 0):

En este caso ya que no se tiene que pasar props a varios niveles de componentes creo que useState es suficiente en lugar de useContext.

Aquí esta el código que he cambiado, en resumen, use una constante Products para la información general de productos, una variable cartData con useState para el carrito de compras, y la función getDataProduct  que actualiza la cantidad. (El componente Cart solamente muestra la información del carrito en el navegador que también se puede ver en react developer tools)

```
const Products = [
  {
    name: "ABC",
    id: "p001"
  },
  {
    name: "DEF",
    id: "p002"
  },
  {
    name: "XYZ",
    id: "p003"
  }
];

const ListCardProduct = () => {
  const [cartData, setCartData] = useState([]);

  const getDataProduct = (e) => {
    setCartData((prev) => {
      return prev.some((p) => p.id === e.target.id)
        ? prev.map((p) => (p.id === e.target.id ? { ...p, qty: p.qty + 1 } : p))
        : prev.concat({
            ...Products.find((p) => p.id === e.target.id),
            qty: 1
          });
    });
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {Products.map((product) => {
        return (
          <CartProduct
            key={product.id}
            product={product}
            getDataProduct={getDataProduct}
          />
        );
      })}
      <Cart products={cartData}></Cart>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default ListCardProduct;

const CartProduct = ({ product, getDataProduct }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{product.name}</p>
      <button id={product.id} onClick={getDataProduct}>
        Add to cart
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

const Cart = ({ products }) => (
  <div style={{ position: "absolute", right: 0, top: 0 }}>
    <h3>Cart</h3>
    {products.map((p) => (
      <div key={p.id}>
        product: {p.name}
        <span> number: {p.qty}</span>
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
);
```

Espero te sirva saludos!